# Performance difference between nested bool queries and non nested bool queries in Elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

Was wondering if there's a big difference in performance between these two queries which get the same results

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "color": "red"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "fruit": "strawberry"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and

```
{
  "query": {
      "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "color": "red"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "fruit": "strawberry"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The execution plan of both queries is exactly the same. Add `?explain=true` to your URL so you can see how both queries are "explained".

The performance improvement would come from using `filter` instead of `must` provided you don't need scoring but only yes/no filtering, i.e.:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [                    <-- change this
        {
          "term": {
            "color": "red"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "fruit": "strawberry"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the insight @Val! aside from the improvement using `filter`, i used the explain API and seems like both queries i mentioned in the post will yield the same results with the same performance. Is that correct, as in nested bool queries won't slow down the speed of the search?

Comment: No, don't worry, filters are usually fast... faster than full-text queries